# How to attach bowden tubing to other side of extruder?

Tags: filament, diy-3d-printer

I built a drybox to house the filament roll but now I have to figure out how to attach the PTFE bowden tubing to the other side of the extruder.

Currently the filament just feeds in through the countersunk hole on the MK8 CR-10 style extruder tension lever, but is too close to the Z leadscrew to tap the hole and put a PC4-M6 push fitting.

What is the preferred way to attach this?

THanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to mount a PTFE tubing to the extruder's feeding side.

## Connector solution

You'll need a pair of PTFE tubing couplers, a length of PTFE tubing and tapping tools for the mounting, and the lever should be **metal**:

1. Disassemble the extruder
2. Take the intake side lever
3. open up the intake hole to your PTFE tube connector's inner diameter (that is the diameter, where you cut the thread from!)
4. tap the hole
5. screw in PTFE coupler
6. connect to intake tube
7. Repeat 3 to 6 for the drybox side, possibly add a nut from the inside
8. Feed filament through the tube

If you have a **plastic** side, it reads like this, and you will need an insert that fits your adapter's screw:

1. Disassemble the extruder
2. Take the intake side lever
3. open up the intake hole to a bit under your insert's outer diameter
4. use a soldering iron to melt the insert into the lever
5. screw in PTFE coupler
6. connect to intake tube
7. Repeat 3 to 6 for the drybox side
8. Feed filament through the tube

## free "inner" side

Instead of using 2 connectors on either end of the tube, the one on the extruder can just be "slid" into the block and then fastened.

1. disassemble the extruder
2. take the intake side lever
3. drill open till the PTFE tube can slide in snugly into its rest position against an inner ledge.

   1. For REALLY hygroscopic material, drill *through*
   2. drill a side-hole and use a small screw to fasten the tube in place
   3. alternatively, use hot glue on the outside and secure the tube.